# How to release the connection using Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

after a few requests in my web-application I got this exception:

> java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.

To be clear, I did't configure connection pool(Hikari).
There are all my properties in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/authHibernate
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver 
Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false  
for exceptions
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

My goal was to use usual Hiberante in my Spring-Boot app(not a easy Spring Data way with all these JpaRepo<> and CrudRepo). I got session from EntityManager for this and work with it as in usual Hibernate. The DataSource is responsible for the Connection Pool as I understand. But this thing is the JDBC thing. How should I fix my connection pool with the Hibernate way, not JDBC way? 
There is one of my Dao Classes :

```
@Component
public class GrowBoxDaoImpl implements GrowBoxDao {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public List<GrowBox> findByUser(Long userId) {

    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    String hqlQuery = "from GrowBox gb where gb.responsibleUser.id =: userId";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hqlQuery);
    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    List growBoxes = query.getResultList();
    session.close();
    return growBoxes;
}

@Override
public GrowBox findById(Long id) {

    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    GrowBox growBox = session.get(GrowBox.class, id);
    session.close();

    return growBox;
}

@Override
public GrowBox saveBox(GrowBox box) {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    session.saveOrUpdate(box);
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit(); // call flush too
    session.close();
    return box;
}

@Override
public void deleteBox(Long id) {

    String hqlQuery = "delete GrowBox where id =: id";
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();

    session.createQuery(hqlQuery).setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
}
```

I have a few entities and the Dao Class and Service for each. Also a few Controllers where my Services are used. There is the Git Repo of my application if it helps : https://github.com/DennisKingsman/HibernateWithSpringBootExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical Hibernate with Spring-boot case you can just include

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntitiyManager entityManager;
```

and the spring-boot takes care of creating `EntityManager`s automatically. It also keeps a EntityManagerFactory automatically. No need of explicitly using `EntityManagerFactory`. This is called container managed Transactions. The session is closed automatically.

The EntityManager is managed as a `ThreadLocal` (by Spring-boot) so you may not have access to the same one in another Thread.

Another way is to use Application managed transactions. Read about it at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbra/index.html

Comment: and then I can do smth like : 
        entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession(); and work with my session , but what is the difference between this way and my if I still want to work with session?

Comment: `EntityManager` and `Session` are synonymous and `EntityManagerFactory` and `SessionFactory` are synonymous. former refers to one (active) connection and latter refers to connection factory from which you obtain connections. so you cant do `entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)`.

Comment: Thanks fow the explanation. To be sure, session is the one (active) connection and entityManager works with connection factory? Because if i write  `entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)`  the idea won't give me an error and i thought it mean I can do it?!

Comment: also how should I configure entityManager bean for using `@PersistenceUnit
private EntitiyManager entityManager;`?

Comment: You only need to configure `EntityManagerFactory`, `EntityManager` is created automatically for u in case of container managed transactions.